# Trigger OnPropertyChanged in PostSharp's INotifyPropertyChanged aspect manually

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, postsharp

I'm using the NotifyPropertyChanged aspect from PostSharp.

I have a situation where I need to trigger the `PropertyChanged` event manually, because my use case seems too complex for PostSharp to figure out. Here's the relevant excerpt from my view model:

```
private RelayCommand _authenticateCommand;
[IgnoreAutoChangeNotificationAttribute]
public ICommand AuthenticateCommand
{
    get { return _authenticateCommand ?? (_authenticateCommand = new RelayCommand(Authenticate, _ => IsNotAuthenticated)); }
}

private void Authenticate(object obj)
{
    var result = _dialogService.OpenAuthenticationDialog();
    if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
    {
        _mainViewModel.Update();
    }
    // At this point I need to trigger NotifyPropertyChanged for IsNotAuthenticated,
    // because the authentication dialog causes changes
    // to the _authenticationViewModel's IsLoggedIn property.
}

public bool IsNotAuthenticated
{
    get
    {
        return !_authenticationViewModel.IsLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

As described in my comment in the code above, when the authentication dialog is finished, I need to trigger the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event for `IsNotAuthenticated`, because it's likely that the dialog changed the value.

Reading [the documentation](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_patterns_model_notifypropertychangedattribute), it seems like it should be easy:

> Target classes can customize the NotifyPropertyChangedAttribute aspect by implementing one or many of the members documented in the NotifyPropertyChangedAttributeTargetClass class.

and from the [NotifyPropertyChangedAttributeTargetClass.OnPropertyChanged](http://doc.postsharp.net/m_postsharp_patterns_model_notifypropertychangedattributetargetclass_onpropertychanged_762235a2) page:

> Raises the PropertyChanged event. If this method is already present in the target code, the NotifyPropertyChangedAttribute aspect will use it to raise the PropertyChanged event. Otherwise, the aspect will introduce the method into the target class.

Great, so I tried implementing an empty `OnPropertyChanged` method in my view model, thinking that it would be replaced by PostSharp's version, but alas, it instead just broke all notification logic. This is how the generated code looks before I replace `OnPropertyChanged`:

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    this.<>z__aspect0.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
}
```

and this is how it looks after:

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    this.<>z__aspect0.OnMethodEntry(null);
    try
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        this.<>z__aspect0.OnMethodExit(null);
    }
}
```

Testing the code, it works in the first case, and not in the second. So my implementation of an empty `OnPropertyChanged` causes the feature to stop working.

I guess the documentation is lying? It explicitly says (emphasis mine)

> If this method is **already present** in the target code, the NotifyPropertyChangedAttribute aspect **will use it** to raise the PropertyChanged event." -- but the generated code above and my testing says otherwise.

What I've ended up doing "in the meantime", until I figure out what I am or PostSharp is doing wrong, is create my own aspect, like this:

```
[Serializable]
class PropertyChangedTriggerAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        var inpc = args.Method.DeclaringType;
        if (inpc == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("PropertyChangedTriggerAttribute used on an object that doesn't have an OnPropertyChanged(System.String) method.");
        var opc = inpc.GetMethod("OnPropertyChanged", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var value = (string) args.Arguments.GetArgument(0);
        opc.Invoke(args.Instance, new object[] { value });
    }
}
```

And then tag a method in my class with it:

```
[PropertyChangedTrigger]
private void TriggerOnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{   
}
```

Now I can call that, and it in turn triggers `OnPropertyChanged` for me.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? Anyone gotten this to work for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the following:

> Raises the PropertyChanged event. If this method is already present in the target code, the NotifyPropertyChangedAttribute aspect will use it to raise the PropertyChanged event. Otherwise, the aspect will introduce the method into the target class.

If the method is already present in the class, NotifyPropertyChangedAttribute will use it. That means that the method needs to do the actual notification, because aspect is using it instead of it's own implementation. Hence, you need to raise PropertyChanged event. That implies that you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface yourself like this:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        this.Property1 = 42;
        this.OnPropertyChanged( "Property2" );
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged( string propertyName )
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ( handler != null )
            handler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName) );
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass test = new TestClass();
        INotifyPropertyChanged inpc = Post.Cast<TestClass, INotifyPropertyChanged>(test);

        inpc.PropertyChanged += ( s, ea ) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Notification received for {0}", ea.PropertyName);
        };

        test.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

This way, it is going to work as you want, i.e. the output would be:

```
Notification received for Property2
Notification received for Property1
```

Note that the order is like this because *Property1* change is raised automatically (by the aspect) when the *DoSomething* method is exiting.

Comment: So there's no way to trigger the auto-generated `OnPropertyChanged` without having to implement the whole `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface manually? I'm kind of surprised that's not a common enough use case to be made available, for instance on the `NotifyPropertyChangedServices` class.

Comment: It is not a common use case (to my knowledge). Surely, I would definitely like that feature. Thanks for suggestion with `NotifyPropertyChangedServices`, we will consider it for one of the future versions.

Comment: I managed to re-write my code to not require a manual triggering, but I still appreciate your input and help. :) There was apparently such a feature in something called the [PostSharp Domain Toolkit](http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/The-Definitive-INotifyPropertyChanged-Pt-2), but I couldn't find a version of that compatible with the current version of PostSharp.

Comment: Yes, that is possible, but the design of the library has changed significantly from that point and so did the Aspect Framework. So if we have dropped that, it was not widely used and probably posed some problems to keep it (or was surpassed with support for already-implemented INPC).